# django check if a model table has a object

Tags: python, django

i have a model like bellow .

```
class User(BaseModel,DjangoUser):
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    realname = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='FollowRelationship', symmetrical=False, related_name='followed_by')

    def follow(self, person):
        relationship, created = FollowRelationship.objects.get_or_create(from_person=self,to_person=person)
        return created

   def unfollow(self, person):
        fs = FollowRelationship.objects.filter(from_person=self,to_person=person)
        if fs is not None:
            fs.delete()
            return True
        return False

class FollowRelationship(models.Model):
    from_person = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='from_user')
    to_person = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='to_user')
    follow_time =  models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

if i have two uses A and B , i use `A in B.followers.all()` to check if A is following B .
is it good to do this , if B.followers have 10000000 objects , is it a good way to do this ?

another question is that if i do follow a User in my (android) application , the `A in B.followers.all()` will return false for sometime and return true . if i restart the django server , it will become true immediately。 what's the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

From documentation it seems [`.exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exists) is more appropriate and faster.

You can check as

```
if B.followers.filter(from_person=A).exists():
```

For 2nd question, it might be django queryset caching issue. Is it in some view?